# Citation of which Donald Knuth's work is meant here?

Tags: combinatorics

I am searching for the work that was cited on Wikipedia here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number

[image]

[image]

In Section Stirling numbers with negative integral values, there is [12] cited and [12] is  D.E. Knuth, 1992. Which work of Knuth's work is meant here?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's on the same page, farther down under “further reading”:

   [image: screenshot of citation from wikipedia page]
2. I did Google search for `knuth 1992` and the top hit was:

   “Two notes on notation”
   Donald E. Knuth
   https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9205211

   The abstract includes:

   > The second notation puts Stirling numbers on the same footing as binomial coefficients. …